# Is it possible to Hide Operator Properties from the Keymap Editor?

Tags: scripting, add-on, shortcut, properties

I know you can hide properties from the Redo Panel with `options={'HIDDEN'}` or with a custom draw() method, but what about hiding them from the Keymap Editor.

EXAMPLE of properties I would like to hide from the Keymap Editor:

[image]

I'm using:

```
layout.context_pointer_set('keymap', km)
rna_keymap_ui.draw_kmi([], kc, km, kmi, right, 0)
```

... to draw the keymaps in my addon preferences, but every single property is laid bare, even hidden ones. I have some values stored in those properties that I re-use between operator runs, which I would prefer I could hide from end users so they don't change them.

It's not critical that they're hidden (nothing will break), just wondering if there's something I can learn about drawing keymaps or is my only alternative to hide those values somewhere else, maybe grouped scene properties or something?